# Javascript Regular Expression - Wacky String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string (below) that I need to extract certain data between two characters.

```
var str = "%T4271445443612318^MARK/Wdogn^14011011002033da?;411111111111111=140ke011lmn0529oqme00?";
```

I need to capture this number: **411111111111111**
It is between a ";" and "=" always.

Any help I am still new to RegEx.

Answer (score 4):

This would be `;(\d+)=`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html is your friend. :)

Answer (score 4):

how about something like

```
;(\d+)=
```

which does the following:

- matches `;` char
- `\d+` matches one or more numeric char
- the `(` and `)` capture the number into a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `=` matches the equals char at the end

Answer (score 1):

```
var fourOneOne = str.match(/;(\d+)=/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always formatted as you suggest, you don't need a regex:

```
var str = "%T4271445443612318^MARK/Wdogn^14011011002033da?;411111111111111=140ke011lmn0529oqme00?";
var sub = str.substring(str.indexOf(';')+1,str.indexOf('='));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ym3m/